# c# accessing struct members within class' methods

Tags: c#, struct, member, non-static

i'm trying to write a simple game. I want to design a "movement controller" object, that would handle move instructions from the engine. I would also like for this object to expose a method, that would check its state and return true/false depending if it's ready to move or not. The state will be saved as group of boolean variables. Since there is a lot of them, I decided to group them together in a new struct called "flags". This is how it looks like more or less:

```
public class movContr
{
    int movId;
    public struct flags
    {
        bool isMoving;
        bool isLocked;
        bool isReady;
        (...)
    }

    public bool CheckReadiness()
    {
        if(flags.isReady==true) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is this won't compile, error being:

```
error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member
```

offending line being:

```
if(flags.isReady==true) return true;
```

So I guess C# doesn't treat structs like memory blobs that just contains variables in orders, but like some "special" cousin of a class.

Here are my questions:

how should I handle accessing struct class members in its methods? How can I refer in class methods to members of its future instances? I tried this instead:

```
if(this.flags.isReady==true) return true;
```

but i get the same error.

Alternatively, if encapsulating my flag variables using 'struct' is not a proper way to do so, what is?

I tried to find an answer myself but since all the keywords I could come up with are very generic, so are the results. Most deal with static members, which are not a solution here since I need multiple, independent instances of movContr class.

Comment: I'm not sure you even need a struct here.  It looks like you could just create properties or fields on your class for each of the fields in that struct.

Comment: can't believe it was so simple, sorry I can't accept more than one answer :( some days I feel like I should stick to the assembler I swear

@juharr since this is in very early stage and my memory is really bad I want to keep it as readable as possible in case I need to take a break from the project. it doesn't neet to be struct, but I would like to be address the flags in a fashion similar to movContrObj.flags.isMoving, at least for now

Comment: Personally I find the use of a struct here to be less readable, but if you are more comfortable with it then there isn't any real harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created  a declaration of struct called  `flags`.
But it is only declartion, not a concrete value. So, the snippet

```
if(flags.isReady==true) return true;
```

tries to access static member (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

You need to declare a variable of that type in order to use it:

```
private flags myFlag;

public bool CheckReadiness()
{
     if(myFlag.isReady==true) return true;
      return false;
}
```

Maybe your confusion comes from C++, where "inline, anonymous" struct is allowed:

```
struct {
    int some_var
} flags;

flags.some_var = 1;
```

**It is not available in C#**

Comment: I come from more low level background, using things like operator overloading still makes my ankles swell sometimes :) that said, if I ever work out all the quirks, language like C# seem to be perfect to script games and such (not sure how it does performance-wise though)

Answer (score 0):

As exception suggests You need to create instance of struck as shown below :-

```
flags flag;
flag.isReady = true;
```

For more information :-

http://www.dotnetperls.com/struct

> Please notice how, in Main, the struct is created on the stack.
>   No "new" keyword is used. It is used like a value type such as int.

By the way i would suggest you to use **auto implemented properties** instead of Struck if this is the only use as shown in your code

Ref:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `flags`, because you are only declaring a datatype with "struct flags". You need to create an instance.

and you should declare the fields of the struct as public. otherwise you can't access them.

```
    int movId;

    // Delace fields as public
    public struct flags
    {
        public bool isMoving;
        public bool isLocked;
        public bool isReady;
    }

    // create a instance
    private flags myFlag;

    public bool CheckReadiness()
    {
        if(this.myFlag.isMoving == true) return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Better Implementation
    public bool CheckReadiness()
    {
        if (this.myFlag.isMoving) return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Best Implementation
    public bool CheckReadiness()
    {
        return (this.myFlag.isMoving);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the struct it might make more sense to have properties.

```
public class movContr
{
    int movId;

    public bool IsMoving { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public bool IsReady { get; set; }
        (...)
}
```

Then instead of calling `CheckReadiness` you'd just call `IsReady`.

```
var temp = new movContr();
if(temp.IsReady)
{
    // It is ready.
}
```

Comment: this makes sense now, but later checking readiness might get pretty heavy on CPU and I will need the cached value somwhere anyway, so it doesn't get executed over and over

Comment: Auto properties are just short hand for getter and setter methods to a backing field.  Not sure how that would increase the load on the CPU over a method that returns a value from a struct.  In both cases the values being accessed are in the stack.

Comment: What I meant is, right now CheckReadiness() only checks value of isReady, but hopefully in near future it will include some complex calculations too. So it will be better for me to call CheckReadiness() only when I really have to, and its result will be cached in isReady for later inexpensive access.